# I am a newbie to coding and solidity

Tags: solidity

I have never done any coding in my life and I have started with solidity. I am following a free online beginner course on smart contracts and somehow I am getting this error:

> contracts/simplestorage.sol:13:29: ParserError: Expected primary expression.
> People public person = ({FavouriteNumber: 2, name: "MB"});

for the following line of code:

```
People public person = ({FavouriteNumber: 2, name: "MB"});
```

Though this is exactly what was shown in the tutorial. Please help.

Comment: can you post a bigger part of the code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the type on the right side of the expression as well.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract MyContract {
    struct People {
        uint256 FavouriteNumber;
        string name;
    }

    // see the `People` type on the right side
    People public person = People({FavouriteNumber: 2, name: "MB"});
}
```

In this case it might seem like a duplication. But it's there because some types can be casted to others. So you could also do this:

```
uint256 number = uint8(100); // small integer to large integer
bytes b = "hello"; // string literal to bytes array
// ... etc
```